# MacBook Pro 2020 M1 stuck on progress bar after login was successful

Tags: apple-silicon

I tried to update to the newest Big Sur 11.5.2 (hat 11.5 already installed). After 3 hours stuck on install screen I tried to reboot and the login panel came up, but when I sign into my admin account, the FileVault progress bar appears for 1 second and then the black background with apple logo replaces with a progress bar of 5% and get stuck on this forever. So there must be anything wrong on the update before.

I tried First Aid on Recovery on my HD Drive and also reinstalled MacOS twice. Every time I start up, the login form came as expected and then after login it changes to the black screen apple logo progress bar 5% again. I also tried secure mode.

Since I never faced such an error, I do not know what to do now. There is no such thing as booting in Single-User or refresh the NVRAM on a M1 silicon mac.

Any other ideas?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Have you tried using the erase this mac option in the recovery partition? If you have data you can try to back it up first https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchlb37e8ca7/11.0/mac/11.0

Comment: You can try boot in Safe Mode : https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac